# Forward mail using Postfix move FROM to REPLY-TO then rewrite FROM

Tags: email, emailrelay

What I am trying to do is:

Setup a SMTP relay for outgoing mail where:
(a) All From: headers are rewritten to be "no-reply@example.com"
(b) A Reply-To: header with the original From: address is added

I am using **sender_cannoical_maps** and **header_checks**, with the content of each as follows:

sender_canonical_maps:

```
/.*/    no-reply@example.com
```

header_checks:

```
/^From:(.*)$/   PREPEND Reply-To:$1
```

But when a message is received, the no-reply address is included in the Reply-To: field, which I do not want:

```
to:         end-user@example.com
from:       no-reply@example.com
reply-to:   no-reply@example.com, sender@domain.com
```

If I change header_checks to use REPLACE instead of PREPEND I lose the original sender which is overwritten:

```
to:         end-user@example.com    
from:       no-reply@example.com
reply-to:   no-reply@example.com
```

So I have lost sender@domain.com.

What I am doing wrong here? And apologies in advance for any lack of info.

Comment: I have the same question, did you get a solution from anyone?

Comment: Me too, same question. Any solution to the problem in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 3):

If `header_sender` is in `sender_canonical_classes` (default) then postfix will rewrite both the From and Reply-To headers when processing `sender_cannonical_maps`. So the `header_check` adds the Reply-To and then the `sender_cannonical_maps` is rewriting the Reply-To. To keep your Reply-To added in `header_checks` you need

```
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
sender_cannoical_maps = static:no-reply@example.com
```

However this leave the From header unchanged, but you can rewrite it in `smtp_header_checks` by adding

```
smtp_header_checks = regex:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
```

`/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks` contents

```
/^From:(.*)$/   REPLACE From: no-reply@example.com
```